# Ошибка при компиляции SFML программы

Tags: sfml, mingw, c++, ubuntu

Ubuntu 12.04 (eOS Luna), glew 1.6 (+ dev), SFML 2.2, Code::Blocks (ночная сборка).

Пытаюсь изучить SFML, открываю урок и всё делаю по уроку.
В точности повторяю всё, что написано. 
При компиляции проекта получаю целую стопку ошибок glew. Переустанавливал GLEW, ставил различные ненужные библиотеки... Результата никакого... 
Долгое скитание по форумам также не дало ответа. Видимо, ни у кого такой ошибки нет...

Comment: @Georgy Linkovsky, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Чудес не бывает, видимо, вы что-то неправильно установили.

Попробуйте привести ваши сообщения об ошибках, они, возможно, натолкнут кого-нибудь на мысль.